# How to add a button to a column in ng2table in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using ng2table but here all the columns are getting appended from ts but i want to add a button to this columns and how can i do that?Can anyone help please.Thanks.

```
      columns: Array<any> = [
    {title: 'Name', name: 'name'},
    {title: 'Position', name: 'position', sort: false},
    {title: 'Office', name: 'office', sort: 'asc'},
    {title: 'Extn.', name: 'ext', sort: ''},
    {title: 'Start date', name: 'startDate'},
    {title: 'Salary ($)', name: 'salary'}
  ];
```

I want to add button 
Delete

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple solutions posted at the end of this issue log. There was also word of updating the ng2-table at some point to have more flexibility with things like this, but not sure if that's still happening. Take a look here:
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table/issues/51